# Removing mysql-server fails

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I reckon there is some dirt in my MySQL installation.

Luckily there is no important data in it, so removing it is safe.

But this fails:

```
# apt remove mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-server' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-47-lowlatency linux-image-5.15.0-47-lowlatency linux-image-lowlatency-hwe-20.04 linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-47
  linux-modules-5.15.0-47-lowlatency mpv python3-brotli python3-mutagen python3-websockets rtmpdump
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 301 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
2022-09-25T06:28:52.470865Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log.
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "restart" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-09-25 08:28:54 CEST; 15ms ago
    Process: 2973216 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2973224 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2973224 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server shutdown complete"
      Error: 22 (Invalid argument)
        CPU: 509ms
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

error.log says:

```
2022-09-25T06:28:51.900261Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 2973147
2022-09-25T06:28:51.945973Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-25T06:28:52.028536Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012962] [InnoDB] The redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo5 size 2531328 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size
2022-09-25T06:28:52.028674Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-09-25T06:28:52.468873Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-25T06:28:52.469418Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-25T06:28:52.469556Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-25T06:28:52.471377Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2022-09-25T06:28:53.854940Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 2973224
2022-09-25T06:28:53.873318Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-25T06:28:53.960339Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012962] [InnoDB] The redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo5 size 2531328 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size
2022-09-25T06:28:53.960464Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-09-25T06:28:54.396861Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-25T06:28:54.397223Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-25T06:28:54.397369Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-25T06:28:54.398649Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2022-09-25T06:28:55.108051Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 2973296
2022-09-25T06:28:55.485639Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-25T06:28:55.609666Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012962] [InnoDB] The redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo5 size 2531328 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size
2022-09-25T06:28:55.609834Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-09-25T06:28:56.015195Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-25T06:28:56.015478Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-25T06:28:56.015565Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-25T06:28:56.016656Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2022-09-25T06:28:56.595908Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 2973388
2022-09-25T06:28:58.730494Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-25T06:28:58.845670Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012962] [InnoDB] The redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo5 size 2531328 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size
2022-09-25T06:28:58.845799Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-09-25T06:28:59.254919Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-25T06:28:59.255193Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-25T06:28:59.255320Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-25T06:28:59.256030Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2022-09-25T06:28:59.849191Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 2973471
2022-09-25T06:28:59.867360Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-25T06:28:59.964204Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012962] [InnoDB] The redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo5 size 2531328 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size
2022-09-25T06:28:59.964306Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-09-25T06:29:00.399579Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-25T06:29:00.400278Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-25T06:29:00.400857Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-25T06:29:00.402213Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2022-09-25T06:29:01.104535Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 2973552
2022-09-25T06:29:01.122430Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-25T06:29:01.218303Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012962] [InnoDB] The redo log file ./#innodb_redo/#ib_redo5 size 2531328 is not a multiple of innodb_page_size
2022-09-25T06:29:01.218391Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-09-25T06:29:01.651901Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-25T06:29:01.652470Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-25T06:29:01.652638Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-09-25T06:29:01.653951Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

How do I force uninstallation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431372/removing-broken-packages-in-ubuntu

Comment: sudo dpkg --purge --force-all mysql-server-8.0